# Overloading + in case of a string literal to another is different than overloading a reference with a string literal

Tags: java, string, operator-overloading

In java for below code:-

```
s1="ab"
s2="a"
s1=="a"+"b" 
s1==s2+"b"
```

The first comparison returs true and second comparison returns flase. Why so?

**Note:- both results in "ab" string only**

Comment: Someone asked this just yesterday -- I guess you're also reading the Head First Java book (it's really popular, after all).

Comment: Take a look here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I found below answer for the above question:   "a"+"b" gets computed at compile time and gets stored as "ab". However s2+"b" gets computed at runtime and whike doing so jvm creates a new java string object in heap space.. I tried changing s2 as final s2.. This resulted in second comparison to true as s2 becomes compile time constant